# Mapping a nested JSON response obtained using RxJava and Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, retrofit

I starting out with RxJava and Retrofit and wanted to create a simple app to show a list of 100 cryptocurrencies.

I am making an api call which results in something like this :

```
{
    "Response": "Success",
    "Message": "Coin list succesfully returned!",
    "BaseImageUrl": "https://www.cryptocompare.com",
    "BaseLinkUrl": "https://www.cryptocompare.com",
    "Data": {
        "LTC": {
            "Id": "3808",
            "Url": "/coins/ltc/overview",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/19782/ltc.png",
            "Name": "LTC",
            "CoinName": "Litecoin",
            "FullName": "Litecoin (LTC)",
            "Algorithm": "Scrypt",
            "ProofType": "PoW",
            "SortOrder": "2"
        }
        ...
    },
    "Type": 100
}
```

But all I want from this is "Response" and "Data". Since it is not practical to create a 100 different model classes for each coin, I want to store information of all the coins in a common class named Coin which would look something like this :

```
public class Coins {

    @SerializedName("Algorithm")
    private String mAlgorithm;
    @SerializedName("CoinName")
    private String mCoinName;
    @SerializedName("FullName")
    private String mFullName;
    @SerializedName("FullyPremined")
    private String mFullyPremined;
    @SerializedName("Id")
    private String mId;
    @SerializedName("ImageUrl")
    private String mImageUrl;
    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String mName;
    @SerializedName("PreMinedValue")
    private String mPreMinedValue;
    @SerializedName("ProofType")
    private String mProofType;
    @SerializedName("SortOrder")
    private String mSortOrder;
    @SerializedName("Sponsored")
    private Boolean mSponsored;
    @SerializedName("Symbol")
    private String mSymbol;
    @SerializedName("TotalCoinSupply")
    private String mTotalCoinSupply;
    @SerializedName("TotalCoinsFreeFloat")
    private String mTotalCoinsFreeFloat;
    @SerializedName("Url")
    private String mUrl;

    public String getAlgorithm() {
        return mAlgorithm;
    }

    public void setAlgorithm(String Algorithm) {
        mAlgorithm = Algorithm;
    }

    public String getCoinName() {
        return mCoinName;
    }

    public void setCoinName(String CoinName) {
        mCoinName = CoinName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return mFullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String FullName) {
        mFullName = FullName;
    }

    public String getFullyPremined() {
        return mFullyPremined;
    }

    public void setFullyPremined(String FullyPremined) {
        mFullyPremined = FullyPremined;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public void setId(String Id) {
        mId = Id;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mImageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String ImageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = ImageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        mName = Name;
    }

    public String getPreMinedValue() {
        return mPreMinedValue;
    }

    public void setPreMinedValue(String PreMinedValue) {
        mPreMinedValue = PreMinedValue;
    }

    public String getProofType() {
        return mProofType;
    }

    public void setProofType(String ProofType) {
        mProofType = ProofType;
    }

    public String getSortOrder() {
        return mSortOrder;
    }

    public void setSortOrder(String SortOrder) {
        mSortOrder = SortOrder;
    }

    public Boolean getSponsored() {
        return mSponsored;
    }

    public void setSponsored(Boolean Sponsored) {
        mSponsored = Sponsored;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return mSymbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(String Symbol) {
        mSymbol = Symbol;
    }

    public String getTotalCoinSupply() {
        return mTotalCoinSupply;
    }

    public void setTotalCoinSupply(String TotalCoinSupply) {
        mTotalCoinSupply = TotalCoinSupply;
    }

    public String getTotalCoinsFreeFloat() {
        return mTotalCoinsFreeFloat;
    }

    public void setTotalCoinsFreeFloat(String TotalCoinsFreeFloat) {
        mTotalCoinsFreeFloat = TotalCoinsFreeFloat;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return mUrl;
    }

    public void setUrl(String Url) {
        mUrl = Url;
    }

}
```

So finally my mapped response class would look like :

```
public class CoinsListResponse {
    private boolean success;
    private List<Coins> coinsList;

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public List<Coins> getCoinsList() {
        return coinsList;
    }

    public void setCoinsList(List<Coins> coinsList) {
        this.coinsList = coinsList;
    }
}
```

I haven't added @Serialized notations because I don't know what key to annotate it with.

My Retrofit service interface has a method to return the results to this map :

```
public interface CoinService {

    @NonNull
    @POST
    Observable<CoinsListResponse> getCoinList();

}
```

Since, I am a starter with Retrofit and RxAndroid, there might be a better method to do this, which I am not aware of. If so, please mention that as well !! I am trying to get my head around this for days but couldn't find any answer on SO as well.

Please Help !!

Comment: gson deserializer there is nothing to do with RxJava

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how to do such a complex deserialization. I have previously desrialised simple jsons but it is a nested one, having 100 different keys. Never done that.

Comment: use  Iterator<String> keys = jObject.keys(); to get all keys and parse accordinally

Comment: I need to write some custom deserializer ?

Comment: yes http://ramannanda.blogspot.in/2015/02/retrofit-custom-deserializer.html you can refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
private List<Coins> coinsList;
```

to

```
@SerializedName("Data")
private Map<String, Coins> coinsByName;
```

You can then either just use `coinsByName.values()` or call e.g. `coinsByName.get("LTC")`

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try right now, I'll accept if it works. Thank you so much !!

Comment: It returned a Map alright, but I really want a list of Coins as the coins hold additional data.

Comment: Each value (in the key-value pairs of the map) will be a `Coins` instance. For example, given the JSON you posted, you could write code like: `String ltcFullName = response.getCoinsByName().get("LTC").getFullName()`

Comment: @Ayusch if you really truly need it to be a `List`, you could always call `new ArrayList<>(response.getCoinsByName().values())`